# Android: ConstraintsLayout VS No Constraints ViewGroups

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-constraintlayout, android-viewgroup

I have two layouts that provide the same result. The first one has been created without constraints and second one has been created using constraints.The result is composed of two sibling sections (one on top of the other) competing for available space. The Bottom section has priority over the Top section so that the latter must conform to the space that the Bottom section doesn't need. Also the top of the Bottom section is given by the top that has its contents.
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXBtR.png)

To be able to achieve this behaviour using constraints i've had to nest the Bottom section in other ConstraintLayout. Is there another way to achieve the same behaviour using ConstraintLayout without using nesting?
Another problem i've found is that when i'm going to animate the constraints of the views that are inside the nested ConstraintLayout don't execute any animation.The outside views yes. Is it possible to perform nested Constraints animation?
These are the XML used files:

**No Constraints version:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_container">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/remove_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/car_image"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_directions_car_black_24dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/loto_image"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_spa_black_24dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ConstraintLayout version:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_constlayout_container">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top_container_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_constlayout_container"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/remove_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_constlayout_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/car_image"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_directions_car_black_24dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/loto_image"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/car_image"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_spa_black_24dp"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you update to a version 1.1.x of `ConstraintLayout`, you can use a barrier to separate the two sections as follows. The barrier floats above the two `ImageViews` and the bottom of the upper section is constrained to the top of the barrier so, as the barrier floats, the bottom of the top section does as well.

[Here](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/) are the release notes for `ConstraintLayout` 1.0.1 beta 1. This Stack Overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44172288/6287910) has references to some documentation for the new features of `ConstraintLayout`.

If you know that one of the image views will always be taller than the other, you can forego the barrier and just tie the bottom of the upper view to the top of the taller image view.

If you make these changes, you can see where you stand with the animation.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/top_container_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#FF00FF00"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/barrier"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/remove_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.constraint.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:barrierDirection="top"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="car_image,loto_image" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/car_image"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_directions_car_black_24dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/loto_image"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="189dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_spa_black_24dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/car_image"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="322dp" />
```